# data type of a and b in map<int,int> a,b

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn c++. I was struck at map in c++. Can someone qualitatively explain me what is a map and where is it more often used?

Comment: Sorry if it is a stupid question I am new to c++ programming.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken about your argument of `map`'s using a hash table for storing it's values. `unordered_map` works like that. As far as I know, `std::map` is often implemented using RB-trees

Comment: @user3624963 it's a _poorly worded_ question.  Your "I know..." part is incorrect and it's hard to know what you're asking.

Comment: You can find more information about `std::map` at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong about the internals of `std::map` - it uses a data structure with `O(log n)` insertion, query and delete times. IIRC, it's a red-black tree. To answer your question, the objects stored are of type `map<int,int>::value_type` which is `std::pair<const int, int>`. Here's the [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).